# How does the Max function work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Hello i've been following a book to learn kotlin. Following the example i have tried to use the .max function for a mutable map. I can't work out why the Max function isn't working as suggested online. I believe i could use a for statment to get around this issue however i want to learn why it's not working for me.

```
val scores: MutableMap<T, Int>  = mutableMapOf()

fun addScore(t: T, score: Int = 0) {
    if (score >=0) scores.put(t, score)
}
    fun getWinners(): MutableSet<T> {
        val winners: MutableSet<T> = mutableSetOf()
        val highScore = scores.values.max()
        for ((t, score) in scores) {
            if (score == highScore) winners.add(t)
        }
        return winners
```

Comment: "isn't working as suggested online" , how is it supposed to work?

Comment: it's coming up with .max() as unresolved reference however it's meant to find the maximum value in the Map. i probably phrased the question wrong i mean to say i've looked for answers online as to why it's not working, and as i can find it should be working.

Comment: Tip for future success on getting help with your questions: never say "not working". Instead, always say whether it's a (1) compile error, (2) runtime error (crash), or (3) doesn't do what you expected. For (1), always include the error message, for (2), always include the stack trace, and for (3) always tell us what behavior you expected and what behavior you got.

Comment: val scores: MutableMap<T, Int>  = mutableMapOf().
I Thought this line nominated the map as a Int

Comment: Thanks for the Tips i am new to this an probably am going to make a lot more mistakes.

Comment: @Alex.T Yes, I misread the code. I deleted my comment. I am assuming T is some type defined at the class level, or else that wouldn't compile either.

Comment: class Contest <T: Pet> i've given it to the pet class.

max(scorevalues) calling the default max function seems to work but i don't know why the .max function isn't working

Answer (score 1):

The `max()` function was temporarily deprecated in Kotlin 1.4, and in Kotlin 1.5 and 1.6 it shows a compile error and you cannot use it.

In Kotlin 1.7, `max()` is back with new behavior. It throws an exception instead of returning null if the collection is empty. This is more convenient to use if you know for sure the collection is not empty, because it returns a non-nullable `Int` instead of nullable `Int?`.

To get the same behavior as the old `max()` function, you can use `maxOrNull()`.

The official explanation of the above is [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compatibility-guide-14.html#gradually-change-the-return-type-of-collection-min-and-max-functions-to-non-nullable). But I think they forgot to update it to say they postponed the reintroduction of `min()` and `max()` from 1.6 to 1.7.

The reason they did this temporary deprecation was to correct the behavior to match convention for how the function is named. They wanted all functions that return null for failures to have "orNull" in the name. But simply changing the behavior all at once would silently break existing code, so they did it gradually to force people to  modify their code so it won't silently break later.